# change custom design of all product via single query or override rule

Tags: magento

i notice some previous developer followed bad way and added custome deisgn to all products using. so now there are 1000 product , if is impossible to mannualy edit all products and change custom theme value to null, so that theme can use default theme for whole magento .

who can i do this via phpmyadim or any easy way like module override ,please help me fo fix it.........................................

Answer (score 0):

You could write a setup script to loop through every product and delete the custom design and save. Since you only have 1000 products it would not be too bad.
If you want to do this through an observer, you could watch the event controller_action_predispatch and write the observer code like:

```
$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
$currentRequest = $request->getModuleName() . '/' . $request->getControllerName() . '/' . $request->getActionName();
if(in_array($currentRequest, array('catalog/product/view')) {
    // override product custom theme theme with normal theme
    $area = Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getArea();
    Mage::getDesign()
        ->setArea($area)
        ->setTheme('yourthemename');
}
```